# Why do people drink expensive alcohol on purim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The main point of drinking on purim is to be drunk. So why did the Rabbis establish the requirement to drink wine? Vodka gets one there faster and cheaper, so it should be preferable to drink it, as Chas Hatorah al mamonam shel yisrael?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Seriously, this might be answered by what the Bi'ur Halachah writes 695:2 that the whole miracle was done with wine; see there.

Comment: @ba I know. That is why some are makpid to drink only wine

Comment: They didn't have Vodka back then. Alcohol distillation only started [in the 12th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distilled_beverage#Medieval_Europe).

Comment: @DoubleAA you mean four hundred years before the flood? That may explain why people stopped living so long

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55277

Answer (score 10):

We drink wine to remember the miracle. The miracle was about venahafoch hu - whatever the non-Jews wanted to do to us we did to the non-Jews.

One of the things that was supposed to happen to us is "וּשְׁלָלָם לָבוֹז" - take our money and spend it all on booze.

Since a person cannot drink away all his money on cheap vodka, the Rabbis helped us and made us use our money on expensive wine.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that we want to remember the *whining* that Haman did to his wife about Mordechai (which was the beginning of the miracle).